# why does Powershell tell me that my file represents a path when I try to rename it?

Tags: powershell, rename, special-characters

I have a filename "+1.txt" that I wish to rename to "+2.txt"

My Powershell script is:

```
$old = "\+1"
$new = "\+2"
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace $old, $new }
```

This returns:

`powershell : Rename-Item : Cannot rename the specified target, because it represents a path`

How can I correct this?

Comment: The backslash in the string is the problem on Windows that's a character found in a path and it's not possible to have it in the name of a filename

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct escape character in PowerShell is ` (the back tick).

E.g. you would write the following to get a string with a newline:

```
$newline = "`n"
```

In addition, at least in a test, I didn't need to escape it. So just `Rename-Item "+1.txt" "+2.txt"` worked. A try using `-replace` required the backslash in the first argument but not the second. So `$new = "+2"` should work. The reason is that the first argument for `-replace` might be a regular expression. So the term needs a literal + that isn't handled specially. The second term is handeled as a literal string so you don't need any special escaping or similar.

Answer (score 1):

`-replace` uses regular expressions, but you don't need to manually escape chars.
Get-ChildItem iterates all items in the current path, you've to specify a name

```
$old = "+1.txt"
$new = "+2.txt"
Get-ChildItem $old -file| 
  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.FullName -replace [regex]::escape($old), $new }
```

or use a where to `-match` only pattern.

```
$old = "+1.txt"
$new = "+2.txt"
Get-ChildItem | 
  where Name -match [regex]::escape($old)|
    Rename-Item -NewName $new
```

Comment: What would be the advantage of using `[regex]::escape` instead of escaping it by hand? For more complex expression that might be quite useful. In your second example you could just change `-NewName` to `$new` as you''re doing the match to find the file beforehand.

Comment: @Seth, the advantage of using `[regex]::escape` is that he doesn't violate the Don't Repeat Yourself Principle (DRY), which is a very important principle in creating quality software.